# How would I write a recursive function that sums an array of numbers that uses tail call optimization (TCO)?

Tags: javascript, recursion

So I wrote this function that sums an array of numbers using recursion. How would I make this tail call optimized?

```
function sum(array) {
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return array[0] + sum(array.slice(1));
  }
}

sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); // 15
```

Comment: What do you mean, *optimized*? Smaller? Shorter?

Comment: I wouldn't say 'duplicate', but the question [What Is Tail Call Optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization) shows a nice example on how to make the Factorial function tail call optimized.

Comment: @JackBashford I may be wrong but I think the question simply refers to tail call optimization as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization not optimized in terms of the actual code which is written

Comment: It may also be worth noting that support for tail call optimization is fairly poor https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-proper_tail_calls_(tail_call_optimisation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [TCO function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) needs to return a function call, which replaces the last stack item and prevents the stack to grow.

Therfore you need to store the `total` as well in the function as parameter and hand over this value at the ent of the recursion.

```js
function sum(array, total = 0) {
    if (array.length === 0) {
        return total;
    } 
    return sum(array.slice(1), total + array[0]);
}

console.log(sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) there is no need to do a recursive function:

```js
const result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0); // 15

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a ternary operator like so:

```js
const sum = array => array.length ? array[0] + sum(array.slice(1)) : 0;

console.log(sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // 15
```

You can also use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to avoid recursion:

```js
const sum = array => array.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);

console.log(sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: Whilst this is surely a better way to sum the numbers, I believe this question is focused more on the nature of tail call optimization than of summing numbers

Comment: Yes @OliverRadini that is true - just including it for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, tail call optimization (TCO) is not supported in most of browser. You can see support info [here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

You can always use for loop. for loop has higher performance in most of situation.

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; //不含最大值，含最小值
}

function sum_1(arr) {
  var s = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    s += arr[i];
  }
  return s;
}

function sum_2(arr){
  return arr.reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0);
}

var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
  arr[i] = getRandomInt(0,100);
}

let t0 = window.performance.now();
sum_1(arr); // 15
let t1 = window.performance.now();
console.log("sum_1 executed time : " + (t1 - t0) + " ms");


let t2 = window.performance.now();
sum_2(arr); // 15
let t3 = window.performance.now();
console.log("sum_2 executed time : " + (t3 - t2) + " ms");
```